# Meteor.js: How to use a phantom.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, npm, phantomjs

I need to use a phantom with the meteor. If I use a separate script, everything works. If I'm using in with the meteor, I get an error.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
        page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/').then(function(status) {
            console.log(status);
            page.property('content').then(function(content) {
                console.log(content);
                page.close();
                ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
C:\OpenServer\domains\EM-topface-like\node_modules\phantom\lib\phantom.js:53 function createLogger({ logLevel = defaultLogLevel } = {}) { SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\OpenServer\domains\EM-topface-like\node_modules\phantom\lib\index.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10) Exited with code: 1 Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

How to fix?

Comment: The point of promises is to *stop* callback hell from happening, not continue nesting callbacks

Comment: Can you show an example of how to solve the problem correctly?